# PatriciaTrie or HashMap which is best to store large amount of data in session

Tags: java, collections

PatriciaTrie or HashMap which is best to store large(100 Thousands records) amount of data in session. How PatriciaTrie allocate the memory- For example- HashMap allocate the memory by Initial_Size*loadFactor.

Comment: Define `large` - at least as order of magnitude? What? Hundreds of entries? Few Mega entries?

Comment: Do some tests to find out what works better.

Comment: I need an explanation why I am gonna use PatriciaTrie in place of HashMap.

Comment: Large means some where around a million records.

Comment: What is your criterion for deciding which is "best"?  Are you going to want to use the trie-specific API methods?

Comment: @StephenC yes I am planning to implement trie API. Currently I am looking for best replacement of HashMap becuase of memory overhead and I need faster update and retrieval of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I am looking for best replacement of HashMap becuase of memory overhead and I need faster update and retrieval of data.

I don't know if a `Trie` will give you a smaller memory overhead than a `HashMap`.  It depends on the size and distribution of the keys, and on how you implement the Trie.  The same probably goes for speed of lookup and update.

I think you will need to try (no pun intended) both alternatives and **measure** the performance ... with datasets that are **representative** of your actual data.

The other point (which you seem to have misunderstood) is whether you plan to exploit the Trie-specific methods in the API; e.g. `ceiling`, `floor`, `headMap`, `tailMap`, `first`, `last`, etcetera.  If you do, then you need to use a Trie ... or some other kind of navigable map API.  You can't do such things efficiently using a `HashMap`.